# How can I check if two distributions are independent

Tags: self-study

A telephone salesman calls 3 people in a month and sells a product with probability 30%. In each call he sells either 0 or 1 products. He calls three people this month. If he manages to sell the product in his first or second call he gets 100 euro per successful call and 200 if he sells a product in his last call. Let $X$ be number of products he sells and $Y$ the sum of euros he sells. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

I managed to compute total distributions and marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ but how can I compute $\mathbb{P}(X=x\cap Y=y)?$

Comment: I am confused. The more products (X) a salesman sales, the more revenue has been generated (Y) and vice versa. So X and Y are positively correlated. Do I miss something here ?

Comment: @steffen Sorry, in every phone he sells at most one product and so he might get either 0, 100, 200, 300 or 400 euros. And yes, there is a positive correlation between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Since this is homework ... think about the last sentence in your comment. Then think about your question. If you need another hint, think about @steffen 's comment.

Comment: So is the correct way to do it to check if $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ for every pair $(x,y)$ where $x\in\{0.343,0.441,0.189,0.027\}$ and $y\in \{1/4,1/8\}?$ Or does the positive correlation implies the they aren't independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints (for doing it the hard way):

- Let $Z_1$, $Z_2$, $Z_3$ denote the *number* of sales resulting from the first, second, and
  third calls respectively. What kinds of random variables are the $Z_i$'s? (They 
  are not Brand X random variables, they have a specific name that is recognized by most
  people).
- Express $X$, the total  number of sales, in terms of the $Z_i$'s.
- Express $Y$, the total commission earned, in terms of the $Z_i$'s.
- *Now* create a table with 5 rows (for the values of $Y$) and $4$ columns
  (for the values of $X$) and in each of the $20$ cells fill in the probability
  that $X$ and $Y$ have the corresponding values. At most $8$ of the $20$ cells
  will have nonzero entries. (Can you tell why?).
- Now you have the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$, and the
  marginal mass functions are just the column and row sums of the table entries.
  You can
  proceed to verify the hard way whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent by checking
  whether each and every entry in the table equals the product of the corresponding
  row sum and column sum.

---

Hint for doing it the easy way.

Does $X$ take on value $1$ with nonzero probability? Does $Y$ take on
value $400$ with nonzero probability? Do $X$ and $Y$ take on values
$1$ and $400$ *simultaneously* with nonzero probability? (It does
not matter in the least what the exact values of the probabilities are).
If the answers to the first
two questions are Yes, and the answer to the third is No, what does that
tell you?